# Cannot right-click to add row or column in gridbagLayout [Netbeans]

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans-7

I am taking a User Interfaces class at my university and cannot seem to get Netbeans (7.4) to allow me to add rows and columns in the customize layout for the GridBagLayout. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: `GridBagLayout` will "add" columns and rows based on the placement of the components within...

Comment: I should be able to right-click the "add column" button and select "insert column after" but when I right-click nothing happens. This is in the Customize Layout window

Comment: `GridBagLayout` doesn't have a concept for components outside of it's area of effect, so you can't have rows or columns with nothing in them at the outer edges (you can in between components)